# How to set a static html page as homepage of an ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am learning ASP.NET Core Web API. I followed the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#serve-default-documents-1) and created an ASP.NET Core Web API project. but setting a static HTML page is not working.

This is my code:

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "abc's API",
        Description = "abc's Site directory API",
        Version = "V1",
        TermsOfService = new Uri("https://github.com/abc"),
        Contact = new OpenApiContact
        {
            Name = "abc xyz",
            Url = new Uri("https://github.com/abc")
        },
        License = new OpenApiLicense
        {
            Name = "Example License",
            Url = new Uri("https://example.com/license")
        }
    });

    // using System.Reflection;
    string xmlFilename = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    string xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFilename);
    options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
    options.SchemaFilter<EnumSchemaFilter>();
});

builder.Services.Configure<AuthSetting>(builder.Configuration.GetRequiredSection(AuthSetting.AuthSection));
builder.Services.Configure<SPSetting>(builder.Configuration.GetRequiredSection(SPSetting.SPSection));

// Azure log system configuration, default location : D:\\home\\LogFiles\\Application
builder.Logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
builder.Services.Configure<AzureFileLoggerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.FileName = "azure-diagnostics-abc";
    options.FileSizeLimit = 50 * 1024;
    options.RetainedFileCountLimit = 5;
});
builder.Services.Configure<AzureBlobLoggerOptions>(options => { options.BlobName = "abc-log.txt"; });

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseDefaultFiles("/default.html");
app.UseStaticFiles();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
        options.RoutePrefix = "abc";
    });
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Basically, it's near to a newly created project. and I put the HTML page here:

[image]

Swagger and others all work well! but I cannot access to default HTML ("https://localhost:7184/default.html" is always 404)

Please help me!

Comment: The standard default page name is `index.html`, not `default.html`.

Comment: [`UseDefaultFiles` handles both `index.html` and `default.htm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#serve-default-documents). Have you tried *without* hardcoding the path ?  Middleware order matters too. The doc examples put `UseDefaultFiles` and `UseStaticFiles` between `UseHttpsRedirection` and `UseAuthorization`

Comment: all answers are helpful. i change the location of UseDefaultFiles and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to reverse the order

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseDefaultFiles("/default.html");
```

updated:

you don't need to call `app.UseDefaultFiles("/default.html");` at all

Comment: The [documentation example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#serve-default-documents) shows `UseDefaultFiles()` before `UseStaticFiles`.

Comment: yes that is if you call UseDefaultFiles without any parameter.

Comment: A middleware's parameters don't change the order of the middleware filters.

Comment: actually i just tried by removing the complete line "UseDefaultFiles()" and it worked fine and able to load the default.html page

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add `app.UseFileServer()`

Excerpt from MSDN docs e.g. [Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

> Call `app.UseFileServer` to enable the serving of static files and the default file.

Your call to `app.UseDefaultFiles()` should not require the "/default.html" parameter since the documentation says:

> With `UseDefaultFiles`, requests to a folder in wwwroot search for: default.htm default.html index.htm index.html

Comment: Your call to app.UseDefaultFiles() should not require the "/default.html" parameter since the documentation says:

... With UseDefaultFiles, requests to a folder in wwwroot search for:

default.htm
default.html
index.htm
index.html

Comment: Add the extra info to the question itself, not as a comment